# Define the property of $|OA|\leq|OB|$ using equality predicate and a distance predicate

Tags: logic

I got the following question in logic class and a bit stuck with answering any help would be appreciated!

For the next two exercises let the signature contain an equality predicate and a three-placed
predicate $C$. Consider an interpretation in which the domain is a set of points in the plane,
equality is interpreted as a coincidence of points, and $C(x, y, z)$ means that the points $x$ and $y$
have the same distant from the point $z$.
Exercise 3 (2). Define the property $\vert OA \vert \leq \vert OB \vert$ of three points $O, A, B$.
Exercise 4 (1 for each). Define by a formula:
(a) equality of triangles;
(b) equality of angles;
(c) the property of an angle to be right.

as far as for the first question, I was trying to imagine o as the center point of a circle and find a defintion such that if A is closer to the center of a circle than B by adding a fourth point x such that:
(C(A,X,O) and (B,X,O)) imply (B=A) or some other combotion of that but I have failed..

Comment: You will need to use some reasoning about plane geometry for each of these formulae.

Comment: [Tarski's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms#Discussion) will be useful.

Comment: How come ?......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I will start by defining the property of 3 points, $A,B,D$ to be on the same line. It can be defined as:
$$\lnot\left(\exists E\right)\left(\lnot\left(E=D\right)\land C\left(E,D,A\right)\land C\left(E,D,B\right)\right)$$
I will use the predicate $S(A,B,D)$ to write that.

Next, I will defined the property of two lines to be parallel. Given 4 points, $A,B,D,E$ that represent 2 lines $AB,DE$. The lines are parallel if:
$$\lnot\left(\exists P\right)\left(S\left(A,B,P\right)\land S\left(D,E,P\right)\right)$$
I will use the predicate $P(AB,DE)$ to write that. This definition is correct because in a parallelogram, every pair of opposite sides have the same length.

Now, when we have this, I will define the property of 4 points, $A,B,C,D$ to be the vertices of a parallelogram:
$$\left(P\left(AB,DE\right)\land P\left(BD,AE\right)\right)$$
I will write this property using the predicate $L(ABDE)$.

When we got this (and I know it was really long), we can define the property of 2 lines to have the same length. Given 4 points that represent 2 lines, $AB,DE$, the lines have the same length if:
$$\left(\exists Z\right)\left(C\left(D,Z,E\right)\land L\left(A,B,Z,E\right)\right)$$
I will write this property as $\left|AB\right|=\left|DE\right|$

Now, when we got all of that, I will define a more general version of the property you asked for: For every 4 points, $A,B,D,E$: $\left|AB\right|\leq\left|DE\right|$. This property will be defines as:
$$\left(\forall P\right)\left(C\left(D,E,P\right)\to\left(\left(\exists Q\right)\left(C\left(A,B,Q\right)\land\left(\left|BQ\right|=\left|EP\right|\right)\right)\right)\right)$$
where $C$ is the distance predicate, and $C(A,B,D)$ (for example) means that $|AD|=|BD|$.

The explanation for why this definition is correct is that we are looking at points on the bisection of the longer segment. For each point on that, we are searching for a point on the bisection of the shorter segment, such that the lengths (from the point to the edge of the segment in each one of the segments) are the same. We can notice that this definition is correct because such lengths has a minimum value, but doesn't have maximum value (because we can go as far as we want). And also, the minimal value is $\frac{1}{2}$ of the whole segments's length. Thus, if $DE$ is actually longer (or equal), then its minimal value is larger than (or equal to) $AB$'s, and the expression is true. If $DE$ is shorter, then its minimal value is smaller, and the expression isn't true because we can't find a corresponding point ($Q$ in the expression) that will make the expression true.

Now you can just substitute the points that you need and get that the property $\left|OA\right|\leq\left|OB\right|$ can be defined as:
$$\left(\forall P\right)\left(C\left(O,B,P\right)\to\left(\left(\exists Q\right)\left(C\left(O,A,Q\right)\land\left(\left|AQ\right|=\left|BP\right|\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the respone! That seems correct its just I don't think given the interpreation that I can just use absolute value, so mind helping me figureing out what could I replace with |AQ| = |BP|? I was thinking about defining |AQ| <-> C(A,A,Q) but it seems wrong, so if u could help me with that I would apprecaite it !

Comment: Hi, you are correct, I can't just use that. I edited the answer and now it contains the definition of two lines to have the same length (as well as a lot of other definitions that I needed in the way). I hope now its all clear. If you need an explanation about one of the definition, write it here and I will add the explanation.

Comment: I really appracited it ! thank you very much! If u could give me some hints for the other questions it would be very helpful !